# How get range-source when cell was drag?

Tags: google-apps-script

How in script of google sheet I can to get range-source when cell was drag? Is it possible?
I tried to use onEdit(), but I can receive only range-destination or old value in it.

Comment: Excuse me, but I not understand what is "another function".I need to catch event when user will drag any cell.Ending cell I know but I don't know how to found start cell of dragging. GetActiveRange() return ending range, because when onEdit will work, active range is ending range. And I beforehand don't know what cell user will to drag...

Comment: The only way I know how of is with a modeless dialogue, a text box and a button.